# Equivalence vs Equality within non-logic expressions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, relations, equivalence-relations

In mathematics there are a lot of relations, one of which is equivalence ($\equiv$) and its sub-domain equality ($=$). This question doesn't concern the logical equivalence, and stated as:

**Question:** *What is the difference between equivalence and equity within non-logical statements? 
Which operator to use in diffrent cases ?*

A few examples to clarify the question

1) Assume we have a function $A^t(x,y)$ which gives a binomial expansion of $(x+y)^t$, gives exactly the expansion of $(x+y)^t$ for $t\geq 0$, so, since it is essentially the binomial expansion, can we write it as

$$A^t(x,y) \equiv \sum_{r} \binom{t}{r} x^{t-r} y^r ?$$

2) Assume we have a function $P^t(x,y)$ which gives a binomial expansion of $2t+1$ power and plus 1 in implicit form. For example for $t=1$ it gives

$$P^1(x,y) = -1 + x + y - (-1 + x + y) (x + y) (-1 - 3 x - 3 y + 2 (x + y))$$

the binomial expansion of third power is get only after whole result expression is exapnded, i.e

$$P^1(x,y) = 1 + x^3 + 3 x^2 y + 3 x y^2 + y^3$$

In that case, can we write it as

$$P^t(x,y) \equiv 1 + \sum_{r=0} \binom{2t+1}{r} x^{2t+1-r} y^r ?$$

The question arises since, essentially, $P^t(x,y)$ doesnt give binomial exapnsion itself immediately, but only after brackets are expanded.

**PS**. It is possible that the author of a question doesn't understand the concept of equivalence as a whole, and it is useless outside the math. logics, please, clarify it

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a rule of thumb, *equality* must be used with *terms* (i.e. "names" of objects: numbers, functions, etc.) while *equivalence* must be used between statements (e.g. formulas).

Comment: Concerning the examples, are they right or something has to be revised ? Most of interest keeps the example 2)

Comment: $P(x,y)$ is a function: for every pair of values assigned to $x$ and $y$, the expression of $P(x,y)$ outputs a number. Thus, either you are defining a new symbol (the LHS) with the expression to the right, in which case *equality* is appropriate, or you are asserting that the two expession have the same outputs for the same input(s), in which case again you have equality between values (numbers).